# Making a content area appear at bottom of content area when hovering over specific area of a sitemap

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

I have been working on how to hover over an area of an image (in my case the image is a site map of a library) and then a content area about that area appears below the image. So far i have created a div to hold the image and made divs for each area of the map, i have then created seperate divs contating the information. i have been able to align the divs of the areas on the image to the areas i need but am unable to figure out the jquery to make the content information appear at the bottom of the image.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.container img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 180px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 220px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 220px;
}

#left,
#topRight,
#centerRight,
#bottomRight {
  display: none;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 68%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="MelbournePublicLibraryFloorPlan.jpg" alt="Norway">
    <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    <p>On the left of the library you will the book shelves.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="topRight">
    <p>In the top right of the library you will find the computer desks.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="centerRight">
    <p>In the center of the library on the right you will find the reading area. Make yourself comfortable and read a good book.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomRight">
    <p>
      In the bottom right corner of the library you will find the service counters, were you will find friendly library staff
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet for simple jquery to show/hide on hover. I have done below changes,

1. Added `title` common class for all hover-able divs
2. Added `data-id` attribute to all hover-able divs as show-able div's id

```js
$('.title').hover(function() {
  $($(this).data('id')).toggle();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.container img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 180px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 220px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 220px;
}

#left,
#topRight,
#centerRight,
#bottomRight {
  display: none;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 68%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="MelbournePublicLibraryFloorPlan.jpg" alt="Norway">
    <div class="top-left title" data-id="#left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right title" data-id="#topRight">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right title" data-id="#centerRight">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered title" data-id="#bottomRight">Centered</div>
  </div>
  <div id="left">
    <p>On the left of the library you will the book shelves.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="topRight">
    <p>In the top right of the library you will find the computer desks.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="centerRight">
    <p>In the center of the library on the right you will find the reading area. Make yourself comfortable and read a good book.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomRight">
    <p>
      In the bottom right corner of the library you will find the service counters, were you will find friendly library staff
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Do i change the ones inside the div=container to the  title class and then change the ones in their individual divs to id data-id?

Comment: yes you can compare my code with yours to get better understanding.

Comment: hi i have done what you have said and its not working

Comment: then share your code in a fiddler, so that can get it done.

Comment: im not sure what you mean sorry still a newvbie on this site

Comment: i placed it in a fiddler and works but when i open it in firefox or chrome it doesnt

Comment: share your fiddler link here.